# Metaplex Candy Machine metadata not displaying correctly on Solscan

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I am following the Candy Machine v2 tutorial and have hit a bit of a wall when it comes to actually correctly displaying my NFTs.

I think the issue is somewhere in the metadata structure but I have hit a bit of a dead end.

Metadata json of the example file, this is the file from Metaplex:

https://solscan.io/token/GvdHdmKHVuyYXMd2EZrRqgCSqLsmWRfmYt7dNoMo4LZn?cluster=devnet#metadata

I'm not entirely sure where things are going wrong but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify what commands you have run and details of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your uri is currently set to: cryptorockers/ipfs/QmS4doTov9nj43DTv8FXY9YKiLeUodAgfo9P7hikoECtzF which is not a relevent resource. This would explain why your NFTs do not display.